# sklearn SGDClassifier can not make it train or predict deterministically

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm training a simple linear model with the sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier. I was seeing some results where training on the same exact training set would yield drastically different results occasionally. I am trying to run an experiment where I freeze everything about my feature construction pipeline and sample selection to see what kind of effect the initial random state has on classifier results. So here I'm trying to loop over the same fit and predict code multiple times, re-instantiating the classifier object every time and setting the seed to 123456.

```
    classif['classifier'].random_state = 123456
    classif['classifier'].fit(LABELED, LABELS)   
    y_test = classif['classifier'].predict(TEST_LABELED[:1000])                                                                                                                                                                              
    classif['accuracy_over_iter'] = np.append(classif['accuracy_over_iter'], accuracy_score(TEST_LABELS[:1000], y_test))  
    classif["score"] = accuracy_score(TEST_LABELS[:1000], y_test)
    print(f'{classif["description"]} score {classif["score"]}')
```

Afterwards, every classifier I train ends up with a slightly different prediction. Am I not setting the seed properly somehow?

```
reflectance_standard_scaler__SGD score 0.642    
reflectance_standard_scaler__SGD score 0.644  
reflectance_standard_scaler__SGD score 0.632 
reflectance_standard_scaler__SGD score 0.623 
reflectance_standard_scaler__SGD score 0.66
reflectance_standard_scaler__SGD score 0.601 
reflectance_standard_scaler__SGD score 0.671
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that sklearn checks the state of the random_state variable only on instantiation. In this case, I was instantiating somewhere else, and then setting the state after, which was too late, as sklearn had already created its own RNG.

Passing in random_state on instantiation caused deterministic results.